# Is there a way to programmatically access the iOS image describer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

When VoiceOver is enabled, iOS can describe images. If the Image Description option is turned on, this will even create a detailed natural language description of the image.

Is there a way to get this description programmatically? My use case is implementing a thumbnail list, where the image describer only has a tiny image to work with, sometimes with overlaid text, which limits its usefulness. I'd like to give it a slightly larger version of the image and get the description directly so I can set up the accessibilityLabel accordingly.

I just can not find this documented or discussed anywhere, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confirmed by an Apple engineer that there is no public API for this as of iOS 14.

Comment: Uh that really just confirms my answer.

Comment: I won't be answering any of your questions in the future since you only confirmed my answer and took credit for it.

Comment: Ok, but you just guessed, and I actually confirmed it with an Apple engineer.

Comment: It's called "Knowledge" - that is what SO is all about. I work with  deep learning on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

If so, it would be part of the [Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision), and is not currently available. I do not see a image description model in Apple's [Model Zoo](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/) either.

A quick search shows many tutorials on the subject.

Comment: The image description does obviously use Vision internally, but it is much higher-level, so I doubt it would live in Vision. I did check there too, though, also with no success.

Comment: Image Description from an Image is certainly a Computer Vision task. I can not think of any better framework for it. And if it wasn't part of Vision and something Apple wanted to share, it would certainly be in the Model Zoo.

Comment: I don't see how Vision could be considered a low level SDK. Essentially you give it an image and a model it returns prediction results.

Comment: Yeah, but the image description also does natural language work to process those results into actual sentences describing both contents and relationships between them, which is not really vision-related at all.

Comment: It is most certainly related to Vision because the language is inferred from what source? An image! That makes it a visual task without question. We digress. If Apple wanted to share it, and it was not part of Vision, it would be in their model zoo, which its not, so...